# CSS3 Content and wrapper div wont auto Resize

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
 <div id="nav">
        <div id="nav_wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Licensing</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">About us</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Testimonials</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a></li><li>
                <a href="#">Social <img src="image/arrow.png" width="8" height="4" /></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://Youtube.com"><img src="image/social/YouTube.png" width="32" height="32" title="Youtube" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://Twitter.com"><img src="image/social/Twitter.png" width="32" height="32" title="Twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://Facebook.com"><img src="image/social/Facebook.png" width="32" height="32" title="Facebook"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <img src="image/placeholderimg.png">
        <h2>Overview</h2>
        <p>Filler Text</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS3**

```
#content 
{
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    resize: both;

}
#content p
{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ccc;
    min-width: 960px;
}
#content h2
{
    margin: 0;
    color: #ccc;
    min-width: 960px;
}
#content img
{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#wrapper
{
     min-width: 960px;
     width: 50%;
     margin: auto;
}
```

**Fixed CSS3 Code**

```
#content 
{
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    resize: both;

}
#content p
{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #ccc;
    min-width: 960px;
}
#content h2
{
    margin: 0;
    color: #ccc;
    min-width: 960px;
}
#content img
{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#wrapper
{
     min-width: 960px;
     width: 50%;
     margin: auto;
}
```

So I've been going around looking for a fix to this, but it seems like i can't find one... So I've come to ask the more seasoned programmers here at Stack-overflow. My Problem i have is need need the content div to re-size along with the rest of the elements, but i cant seem to do it properly. I don't want to completely cut it out using overflow, I want it to shrink along with the page re-size. Is there anyway of doing it? Provided above is the css3 code along with the html divs I'm trying to re-size. The main divs I'm trying to re-size is the content, or the wrapper as an over all if possible.

**Edit:** For some reason or the other I did something I cant explain that fixed the code, could some be so kindly and explain to me what I did?

Comment: To what extent do you want to be responsive? Use percentages for widths instead. #content {width:100%}. Do this for the other items too. If you have a min-width, it will only resize down to what you have specified (960px)

Comment: well for this particular website I would like it to only resize to 960px, if I can figure out that I can do the mobile device and tablet @medias with that in formations, but for the desktop site it would be 960px min.

Comment: I have edited my answer. If you have the #content like that, it will re-size until it gets to 960px;

Comment: If your parent has a min-width of 960px and the children have widths of 100%, the children will still only go to 960px.

Comment: Also, you have a #wrapper selector but it doesnt exist in your html. You do have a #nav_wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems by removing:

```css
margin: auto;
```

It somehow auto-configured it to what I wanted it to do. Would anyone be able to help me understand this?

Comment: Rather edit your original question than answering it.

Comment: Well the original question was to find out how to do it, but i touched something in my code and it fixed it would that need me to alter the question? I thought i could answer myself?

Comment: It didnt make much sense. The margin: auto; is on a selector that doesn't exist in your demo code up above. Because of that I have no idea why it worked, so I can't explain it you. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```css
width: auto;
```

Once try applying this to your code along with `min-width`. I don't know whether it works or not, but once give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The CCS3 property for `resize` allows the user to drag and resize the content div. You should use;

```css
width: auto;
```

or you could use;

```css
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the fiddle. You do not need to set the widths of p or h tags. They usually take up the full space.

Setting the containers to width: 100% should do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/92gnt7qt/4/

```css
#nav {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 960px;
}
#nav_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 960px;
}
```

If your parent has a `min-width` of 960px and the children have widths of 100%, the children will still only go to 960px.